# Display 2 or more textviews in one row

Tags: java, android, textview

I saw some same questions, but
I'm using `android:orientation="vertical"`
so I can't use orientation as horizontal.
How can I display 2 or more textviews on 1 row?
(Sorry for my english skills)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:weightSum="1">
<TextView
        android:layout_width="62dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Sign in"
        android:textColor="#7041EE"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nwah"
        android:layout_width="162dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="New around here?"
        android:textColor="#ACACAC"
        android:textSize="20dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFsvb.png)

Comment: do you want the second textview towards the right end or just next to first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:weightSum="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Sign in"
        android:textColor="#7041EE"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nwah"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="New around here?"
        android:textColor="#ACACAC"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another view for textView

```
<LinearLayout // vertical
 <LinearLayout // hotizontal
  <TextView/>
  <TextView/>
 <LinearLayout/>
<LinearLayout/>
```

or you can use [Constraint layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)